# Installation error with easy_install

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

When I run the following:

```
PS C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Scripts> .\easy_install python-nvd3
```

I receive the following error:

```
Searching for python-nvd3
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-nvd3/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-nvd3/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'python-nvd3' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for python-nvd3
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('python-nvd3')
```

I'm following the installation instructions exactly as they're listed in the library's [website](http://python-nvd3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html).

Please note: I know many would advise me to use pip instead of easy_install. Unfortunately, pip doesn't appear to be an option on my work PC. I receive the following error:

`Connection to pypi.python.org timed out.`

Comment: You received the same error ("timed out") using `easy_install`, also.  It looks like maybe your system is unable to access the pypi website.  Can you load https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-nvd3/ in a browser on the same system?

Comment: Wow, it was that easy! Does every library have a browser-based means of downloading? Would I be able to find the necessary folders for any library by going to pypi.python.org/simple/[library name]? I'm not sure why I keep getting time out errors on my PC.

Comment: Well, I wasn't suggesting using the browser to download the library...I was really just curious if you were able to open it.  In theory if your browser is able to access that web page, the installation tools should also, unless there is some sort of proxy in between you and the rest of the world that only your browser knows about.

Comment: ...but to answer your question, sure.  `easy_install` and `pip` operate over http just like your browser, so you can always just download a package and install it locally.  It's much less convenient, and you'll need to manually resolve dependencies.  I would work on getting the installers to work.

Comment: Perhaps it's some kind of a firewall issue with my employer? I know the security settings are pretty high. If so, maybe it's an issue IT can help resolve.